# Create another project for entity framework migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm creating an ASP.NET WebAPI project, and I would like to know if is better to have a separated project for Entity Framework Migrations.
Creating a separated project, requires to DbContext to be defined in the Migrations project, so should I create a "data" project and let my model classes public, or should I have Migrations in my main project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general software design, this falls under the principles of abstraction, separation of concern, loosely coupled design, etc..  And is absolutely something you should get in the habit of doing.

So.. for serious efforts, the short answer is "yes, put this in a separate project."